# index.js:1 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument

Tags: javascript

index.js:1 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

```js
const logon = async (email, password) => {
  setValores({
    email: email,
    password: password
  }, () => {
    document.getElementById('loginSubmit').click();
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you edit your code and describe the problem and what you are trying to do! This topic may help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Please, when you post a question, make it an actual question. Post the code you tried to run, with some information on what the expected outcome is. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

As for your problem, [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) doesn't accept a callback as a parameter. If you want to perform an action after `valores` has changed, you can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in the component's body:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (valores) {
    document.getElementById('loginSubmit').click();
  }
}, [valores])
```